# About the optimality of a capacitor

Tags: partial-differential-equations, optimal-control

I'm studying Control of PDEs at the University from this [site](http://departamento.us.es/edan/php/asig/MASMAV/MMAAF/L1Presentation.pdf) and these [notes](http://departamento.us.es/edan/php/asig/MASMAV/MMAAF/EFCControl.pdf) and there are some questions I am not capable of resolve. I've never studied EDPs...

So, there are two questions related to the optimatity problem of a capcitor in these notes I would like you to helped me. The problem we are studiyng is:

[image: Control of a capacitor]

And the question I would like to solve and understand are:

1. Interpretation if $a=0$ or $b=0$.
2. Prove or disprove the convergence of this iterative method:

[image]

I am totally lost so any informations, include basic information will be very very apreciated. Thank you.

Comment: i think if $b=0$ then you have the case where you don't penalize the control input (similar to the optimal control for o.d.e. systems). i need to think a bit about the case $a=0$ and question 2.

Answer (score 2):

(1) $a=0$ implies that you do not care about the output $y$, in this case $u=0$ is the optimal control, which is boring.

$b=0$ means you do not penalize control cost. The problem is no longer coercive. If $U_{ad}$ is unbounded the problem might not be solvable.

(2) This iterative method is a fixed point method:

Given $u_{n-1}$ compute $y_n$ from (1.21), then $p_n$ from (1.22), then solve (1.23) for $u_n$. Since $b>0$ (1.23) is uniquely solvable. Its solution being the projection (in the $L^2$ sense) of $-\frac ba p_n$ onto $U_{ad}$.

This fixed point mapping is a contraction if $\frac ba$ is sufficiently large.

Comment: Thank you, I will think about this in the afternoon.

Comment: Why for b=0 the problem is no longer coercive?

Comment: And why the solution is like that?